# Choking browser on html output

Tags: php, macos, firefox, html-table

I have a BIG table to output to HTML and into the browser.  When the table is 200 lines, it's fine, but when it 20,000 lines, it chokes the browser.  I output everything into a variable with `$html .= '<td> and <th>'` and then at the end, `echo $html`.  On my new Mac, with SSD and 32 gig ram, a 20,000 line table takes about 6 seconds to load, but stops everything.  the colorful ball of death spins, the music stops playing, and then the thing appears, and everything continues as normal.

The question is: how do I output a large table in the browser without making it choke?

Note, just as Freddy Mercury said, I want it all, and I want it now.  So, please don't tell me to make a paging table of 20 rows at the time.  I know how to do that, and I don't want to do it.  Anyway, to make it, you have to load ALL THE ROWS, and show only 20, which causes the same choking!

Comment: You're loading a 20,000 line table. It's gonna take a while. I don't understand why you need that to happen.

Comment: It mostly for debuggin puspose, i what to SEE it to KNOW it's there, in the final, it will be filtered and only 10-20 line will be shown, but for now, it's basicly a VISUAL dump of mysql table to screen

Comment: 6 seconds of load time doesn't seem so bad for debugging purposes.

Comment: Can you give it a fixed width and make it `table-layout: fixed`?  That might be a lot faster, since it doesn't have to do automatic column-balancing and whatnot.

Comment: Tables take more time for the browser to render.  The browser tries to calculae the size of the table before it starts rendering it.  If it's just a visual dump of the output, don't use a table at all.  Just output each record followed by `<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyway, to make it, you have to load ALL THE ROWS, and show only 20, which causes the same choking!

That's definitely a bad idea. I would write a method in your model that gets the next n number of records.  You can call this method via Ajax on initial page load, and then again each time the user clicks a "Next N Entries" link and update the page.

You definitely don't want to load the HTML for 20K items and use jQuery to hide and show n records at a time; the DOM traversal will take FOREVER in the good browsers and will completely crash IE.

Comment: Crashing IE.... ahh it's a pretty good thing.. that will tell people, get a real browser or get a life :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you have the content only display the first 20 rows and then as you scroll pull in the additional information via ajax similar to how Facebook and Pintrest works? You can get all the data "eventually", but don't plan on making it work by trying to load it all at once.